# see all commands/logs of screen in linux

Tags: gnu-screen

Let us say I run

```
screen -R myscreen.
```

Then, I run commands on `myscreen` that are bigger than my monitor size so I end up loosing the visibility of the first commands I run.

Then, I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> to leave the screen.

Now I want to see all the commands I ran in `myscreen`.  How would I do that?  How would I see all the history in `myscreen`?  If I do `screen -R myscreen` I am attaching `myscreen` but I can only see the latest commands but they are truncated by the size of my actual monitor and I don't know how to navigate up...

Comment: You mean Ctrl+a d, don't you? Ctrl+d would close the shell, and then you lose the scroll back buffer anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Screen maintains its own scroll back buffer. You can access it like so:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>

You can then use the arrow keys to move up and down through this scroll back buffer. When done hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> again to get out of it.